# First year PhD Student: advices, recommendation, publication and conference

Tags: phd, time-management, reference-managers

I started my PhD 3 weeks ago. I already read a lot of information, research papers, publication and so on regarding my topic, but I still don’t have a complete final idea about my topic. Before applying I was quite sure about my PhD topic idea, but after discussion with other members of research group, my supervisor and attending meetings… I think I have to work on my first idea.

You probably had such experiences and can share your advices, tips, hints which were helpful for your first year in PhD

1. I have a problem with materials I am reading now. To make my notes and highlights (organization) the main idea of papers I read I am using Word, but it doesn’t seem the best idea to do that. Maybe do you have your favourites you used, would happy for all your recommendation?
2. For organizing the tasks I have to do (read, review, send documentation, email…) I am trying to use todolist app, to make my life more “digital”, but I still have a paper notebook to write down my thoughts are coming to my mind during work… and at the end of the day I copy them to app.
3. Is there a platform where I can find all information about upcoming conferences, workshops and meeting I can attend or publish my paper?

I am thinking I have to start a collection of my publication, and maybe I can start with overview of papers I have read

4. How do you organize your work on your project? Do you save your files on cloud (Dropbox, Mega, OneDrive, iCloud, Google drive…) or just on your PC?
5. What was important during your first PhD year?

Comment: *What was important during your first PhD year?* --- This will vary greatly by subject and by country. For example, the primary concern that virtually all graduate students in the departments I was a Ph.D. student in (total of 3; long story . . .) for the first year or two was not messing up too badly in required course work and passing the department's Ph.D. qualifying exam. Reading papers, much less working on research (and even less than this in working on anything for publication), was 2 to 3 years away for nearly all of the first year students.

Comment: Too many questions, can you ask them on seperate posts? It would be better to find the answer you want

Comment: Is there a platform where I can find all information about upcoming conferences, workshops and meeting I can attend or publish my paper? - make that a separate question and I'll happily answer ...

Comment: @WolfgangFahl, thank you for your comment. You will find a new question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191511/first-year-phd-student-conference-journal-for-first-publication-overview-rev)